# Cyclicity and number of maximal subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Given a finite non $p$-group $G$, $G$ has exactly three maximal subgroups then $G$ is cyclic. I suspect that this may be true but don't know how to approach this. Any hint or suggestion is great. The condition for $G$ not being a $p$-group is necessary because Klein 4-group is a counter example as well as $Z_p \times Z_{p^2}$ and take $p=2.$

Comment: Are you assuming $G$ Abelian?

Comment: Are you assuming $G$ finite?

Comment: Yes but not necessary abelian

Answer (score 4):

For finite groups, this below is maybe a partial answer, but provides you with some insight. You probably know that a group with only one maximal subgroup must be cyclic of prime power order. A group with exactly two maximal subgroups must also be cyclic and has precisely two different primes dividing its order:

**Proposition** If $G$ is a group with exactly two maximal subgroups, then it must be nilpotent.

**Proof** Let $M$ be one of the two maximal subgroups. We have to show that $M$ is normal in $G$. Since $M$ is maximal, we have either $G=N_G(M)$ (equivalent to $M \lhd G)$ or $M=N_G(M)$. In the latter case, and because $|G:N_G(M)|$ is exactly the number of conjugates of $M$, we have $|G:N_G(M)|=2=|G:M|$. And it is well-known that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

**Note** In this proposition one can replace "two" by $p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$.

**Proposition** There exists no $p$-group which has exactly two maximal subgroups.

**Proof** Let $G$ be a $p$-group with exactly two maximal subgroups, and let $\Phi(G)$ be its Frattini subgroup. Then $G/\Phi(G)$ has exactly two maximal subgroups, namely the canonical images of the maximal subgroups of $G$. But $G/\Phi(G)$ is an elementary abelian group say of order $p^n$. If $n=1$ then $G/\Phi(G)$ is cyclic, implying $G$ is cyclic and a cyclic $p$-group has a unique maximal subgroup. Hence $n \geq 2$ and we can find an $N \lhd G$ with $G/N \cong C_p \times C_p$. But then $G/N$ has $p+1$ maximal subgroups and the preimages of those in $G$ yield a contradiction.

**Corollary** If $G$ is a group with exactly two maximal subgroups, then $G \cong C_{p^{a}q^{b}}$, with $p$ and $q$ two different primes.

For this $G$ has to be nilpotent, say $G=P_1 \times \cdots \times P_k$, the direct product of its different Sylow subgroups. It is not diffciult to see that the number of maximal subgroups is the *sum* of the number of maximal subgroups of each of the factors. By the previous propositions and the fact that a $p$-group with only one maximal subgroup must be cyclic, the corollary now follows.

The last proposition also implies the following.

**Proposition** Let $p$ be an odd prime. There exists no $p$-group which has exactly three maximal subgroups.

**Proof** Let $M_1, M_2$ and $M_3$ be the maximal subgroups. These all have index $p$ and are normal. Put $N=M_1 \cap M_2$, and assume $N=1$. Then we have $G=M_1M_2$, so $|G|=p^2$, which group has $p+1$ maximal subgroups. So $p+1=3$, a contradiction. Observe that $N \subseteq M_3$, for if not, then $G/N$ has exactly two maximal subgroups, which is impossible by the previous proposition. So $N=M_1 \cap M_2 \cap M_3=\Phi(G)$. Hence $G/N \cong C_p \times \cdots \times C_p $ and this group has $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}=3$ maximal subgroups (with $n \geq 2$). It follows that $p=2=n$ again a contradiction.

Note that $V_4$ as you indicated and also $Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$, have exactly $3$ maximal subgroups. What remains is to classify all $2$-groups with exactly $3$ maximal subgroups.